# Statistical training and modeling noun_chunks in lda2vec

Tags: python, word2vec, lda

I am running a lda2vec (written by chris moody) example code. I am getting the below error when I run the preprocess statement:

```
ValueError: noun_chunks requires the dependency parse, which requires a statistical model to be installed and loaded. For more info, see the documentation:
https://spacy.io/usage/models
```

What should I do? Please help

Comment: I suggest you share this example code with us. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly familiar with this repo...my suggestion would be to update spaCy to 2.0 and follow the example guides from spaCy's site to replicate the spaCy code from v1.0. If you make this question more specific, with an example of the code snippet that is breaking, I might be able to help more. I don't have enough reputation to just leave a comment.

https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features